# Power BI Dax: How to sum without filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a measure to sum [sum of money] column with some criterias just like sumif in excel.

```
TotalSum = 
VAR b = CALCULATE(SUM('SudSOIO'[sum of money]),'SudSOIO'[Main.Filter]="TRUE", 'SudSOIO'[Type of order]="incoming")
RETURN b
```

And ut works perfectly. But It summs values affected by filters. But I dont need it, I need it sum values from whole table without filters applied. Ive tried to use ALL and FILTER(all('SudSOIO') but no luck
What Im doing wrong? Where to put ALL and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try This with All at the end:

```
TotalSum =
VAR b =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'SudSOIO'[sum of money] ),
        'SudSOIO'[Main.Filter] = "TRUE",
        'SudSOIO'[Type of order] = "incoming",
        ALL ( SudSOIO )
    )
RETURN
    b
```

Comment: Hi. Thanx. I've tried but No same result